# $x^5+x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that $h(x) = x^5 + x^2 +1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I have tried applying Eisenstein's criterion to $h(x+1)$ but this didn't work
How would I go about showing it is irreducible?

Comment: One method would be to find all the roots, and all the combinations of them, and show that none of these is in $\Bbb Z[x]$...  Of course there's around $120$ of those combinations, so another method would be preferable, especially since the roots might be difficult to obtain.

Answer (score 4):

Reduce the polynomial modulo $2$, check that it has no root in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and then, if it is reducible must have a factor of degree two. The only irreducible polynomial of degree two over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is $x^2+x+1$ (why?), and then see that this does not divide $x^5+x^2+1$. So $x^5+x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ hence over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: how do i reduce this modulo 2?

Comment: Simply by considering its coefficients modulo $2$. (For more details about the reduction mod $p$ criterion of irreducibility see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875760/a-question-from-the-mod-p-irreducibility-tests-proof.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Alternatively one could try the following: write $$x^5+x^2+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^3+cx^2+dx+e)$$ with $a,...,e\in\mathbb Z$. Then equal the coefficients from both sides starting from $be=1$ which gives $b=e=\pm1$, and so on. In the end you will get that such a factorization is not possible.